# Can I see some output in console instead compiling whole R Markdown when I use knitr

Tags: r, knitr

My question is really simple. When I use knitr to write R markdown, can I see some output in the console instead compiling whole R markdown file? For example, after I wrote the following chunk,

````
```{r}
data1 <- read.table("test.txt")
```
````

if I decide to see the dimension of data1 object, I have to put dim(data1) in the above chunk to see the result in the compiled file(html or pdf), i.e.

````
```{r}
data1 <- read.table("test.txt")
dim(data1)
```
````

But sometimes, I just want to make a quick check and avoid compile the whole R markdown. Can I type dim(data1) in the console or a separated R script file. If I do this directly, R will tell me

```
Error: object 'data1' not found
```

After reminder by Tad Dallas, I figured out after I press the button "Knit Html" in Rstudio, I still have to press button "Run" to get the "data1" in my workspace even if my work space is same as Rmd file location. So question become this: Do I really have to run same code twice?(One is for knitr, one is for R). If the computation causes a lot of time, this means it will double that time. And in a long Rmd which mixes with chunk and text, it will become really annoying to do this.

Comment: If you set your working directory to the same location as the Rmd file, the code should be able to run in the workspace, and you can see the `dim` in your working R instance. Easy enough to use `setwd` command. Does this work?

Comment: No. My workspace are same with Rmd file. I used the knitr to compile Rmd. In Rstudio, after I finished my chunk, I press the button "Knit HTML" to get the html file, the result in html has no problem. However, there is no "data1" object in global environment.

Comment: That makes sense. When you click `knit html`, the `knitr` package extracts and runs the code, and puts the results into another file (html in this case). This is separate from your Rstudio workspace. I'm not sure I'm explaining this correctly, but you can click on `chunks` menu in the top right of your script Rstudio window, and click "Run all chunks". That will run all of your R script through your console, and provide it locally. Does this make sense?

Comment: Great! That works. Thank you so much! So do I really have to run this twice?(One is for knitr, one is for R). If the computation cause a lot of time, this will double it.

Comment: Someone else will probably chime in with a better answer, but I will typically run code that takes a long time to compile in the console, `save.image` or `save` what I need, set the `eval` option to FALSE for code that takes a long time, and then call in the `RData` file in a chunk with `eval=TRUE`, so it compiles quicker. As long as all your code is there to reproduce the analysis, and it's easy to follow what you've done, I don't see much reason to slow down the compilation of a working document.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It is a great and smart solution to my problem. Thanks!